# Convert Set to individual objects in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD in which data is of form 
(x, y), ExampleObject

So, the class has 2 variables:

> 1. tuple consisting of x and y (both are strings)
> 2. exampleObject of class ExampleObject

ExampleObject class further contains 2 attributes:

> 1. setObjects1 of SetObject1 class type
> 2. setObjects2 of SetObject2 class type

Each SetObject1 class further contains 2 attributes:

> 1. singleObject of SingleObject class type
> 2. setObjects3 of SetObject3 class type

You can assume all of the attributes have their getter associated with it. There is another class SingleTransformedObject to which I want to map the singleObject objects.

Now, what I want to do is read this RDD and get the mapped RDD which contains data of SingleTransformedObject list. How can I do that? Some code for initial stages is like this:

```
val filteredRDD = inputRDD.filter { case ((x, _), _) => x == "2321"}
  .map {case (key, exampleObject) =>
    exampleObject.getSetObjects1}
```

Now, after this, I am not sure how can I divide the set of objects to single objects and apply on each of them a transformation.

Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `exampleObject.getSetObjects1` seems to return a `Set` (or other `Collection`), `map` would result in a `RDD<Set<SetObjects1>>`. Based on the question I guess you're looking for `RDD<SetObjects1>`. In that case you need `flatMap` instead of `map`.

```
val filteredRDD = inputRDD
    .filter { case ((x, _), _) => x == "2321" }
    .flatMap { case (key, exampleObject) => exampleObject.getSetObjects1 }
    .map { // code here to convert SetObject to SingleTransformedObject }
```